# Why is Webstorm's Vue plugin not working after being applied?

Tags: vue.js, ide, webstorm

#### Problem

The IDE I'm using for my Vue app (WebStorm) has stopped applying the Vue plugin. It will no longer suggest file paths or recognise the `@` symbol replacing `/src`

#### Setup & Tried Solutions

Here is the current plugin:

[image]

Things I've tried:

- Uninstalling the plugin and then re-installing
- Uninstalling the IDE and then re-installing

But I still get errors like this:

[image]

Are there any additional steps I might be missing? Thanks

---

### Solutions from comments

Thanks to @lena, the fix was simple. In the WebStorm IDE, I completed the following steps:

**Preferences > Languages & Frameworks > Javascript > Webpack**

And ensure that it is set to automatic, mine was set to `Disabled`.

[image]

Comment: do you use Vite or webpack aliases to map `@` to `src`? What WebStorm version do you use?

Comment: WebStorm Version is **2022.2.1** and I'm using webpack

Comment: please share the idea.log (**Help > Show Log in ...**) plus screenshots of **Settings | Languages & Frameworks | JavaScript | Webpack** and **Settings | Languages & Frameworks | Node.js** pages

Comment: @lena can you post this as an answer so I can mark it as correct! Thanks for the help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please make sure that Webpack support is enabled in **Preferences > Languages & Frameworks > Javascript > Webpack**, see https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/2022.2/using-webpack.html